# Can't establish FTP connection outside network

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, ftp, windows-firewall

I'm unable to make a connection with my FTP server running in one Windows 7 computer. My NAT router has the 5000-5100 and 21 ports open, I have my external IP Address, FTP in LAN is up, already tested on ftptest.net and others FTP testers with my external IP Address and all is working fine. But when I try to access it from the browser, it says that the connection is refused. Also tried some Python and C# script to list an FTP Dir, in LAN it's OK, but with External IP, same error.

FTPTest.net output:

```
Status: Resolving address of 192.140.xx.xxx
Status: Connecting to 192.140.xx.xxx
Warning: The entered address does not resolve to an IPv6 address.
Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...
Reply: 220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
Reply: 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
Reply: 220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of 192.140.xx.xxx
Reply: 200 Don't care
Command: AUTH TLS
Reply: 234 Using authentication type TLS
Status: Performing TLS handshake...
Status: TLS handshake successful, verifying certificate...
Status: Received 1 certificates from server.
Status: cert[0]: subject='CN=192.140.xx.xxx,C=55,ST=Bahia,L=Itabuna,O=Contato Pericia Automotiva,OU=Contato Itabuna,EMAIL=gabrielrsantoss@icloud.com' issuer='CN=192.140.xx.xxx,C=55,ST=Bahia,L=Itabuna,O=Contato Pericia Automotiva,OU=Contato Itabuna,EMAIL=gabrielrsantoss@icloud.com'
Command: USER anonymous
Reply: 331 Password required for anonymous
Command: PASS ************************
Reply: 230 Logged on
Command: SYST
Reply: 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
Command: FEAT
Reply: 211-Features:
Reply: MDTM
Reply: REST STREAM
Reply: SIZE
Reply: MLST type*;size*;modify*;
Reply: MLSD
Reply: AUTH SSL
Reply: AUTH TLS
Reply: PROT
Reply: PBSZ
Reply: UTF8
Reply: CLNT
Reply: MFMT
Reply: EPSV
Reply: EPRT
Reply: 211 End
Command: PBSZ 0
Reply: 200 PBSZ=0
Command: PROT P
Reply: 200 Protection level set to P
Command: PWD
Reply: 257 "/" is current directory.
Status: Current path is /
Command: TYPE I
Reply: 200 Type set to I
Command: PASV
Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,140,xx,xxx,19,140)
Command: MLSD
Status: Data connection established, performing TLS handshake...
Status: TLS handshake successful, verifying certificate...
Status: Received 1 certificates from server.
Status: cert[0]: subject='CN=192.140.xx.xxx,C=55,ST=Bahia,L=Itabuna,O=Contato Pericia Automotiva,OU=Contato Itabuna,EMAIL=gabrielrsantoss@icloud.com' issuer='CN=192.140.xx.xxx,C=55,ST=Bahia,L=Itabuna,O=Contato Pericia Automotiva,OU=Contato Itabuna,EMAIL=gabrielrsantoss@icloud.com'
Status: TLS session of transfer connection has been resumed.
Reply: 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
Reply: 226 Successfully transferred "/"
Listing: type=dir;modify=20161214150710; 2016
Listing: type=file;modify=20170808123602;size=2459; 2016 - Atalho.lnk
Listing: type=dir;modify=20170825193146; 2017
Listing: type=file;modify=20141126124218;size=244012; Apresentação1.png
Listing: type=file;modify=20160615135130;size=376600; BOLSONI RASCUNHO.jpg
Listing: type=file;modify=20170306121017;size=349184; Caixa depesas Contato.xls
Listing: type=dir;modify=20170830151015; CONTATO
Listing: type=file;modify=20141126124820;size=21129; CONTATO.jpeg
Listing: type=dir;modify=20170731185326; Documentos
Listing: type=file;modify=20140204041918;size=3049489; DSC00016.JPG
Status: Skipped display of 10 listing lines
Status: Success
```

As I said before, router ports 5000-5100 and 21 are open.

On FileZilla Server Options:

- Passive Mode Settings:

  - Custom port Range: 5000 - 5100
  - External Server IP Address for passive mode transfers:

    - 192.140.xx.xxx
- FTP over TLS settings:

  - Enabled FTP over TLS support
  - Listen for implicit FTP over TLS connections on the default port: 990

No error or Warning on FileZilla interface.

Firewall on Windows:

Created inbound rule to allow connection with protocol TCP on local ports 5000-5100, even added 21 and 990 just to make sure and still with same error, remote ports ALL PORTS.

What else can I do?

Comment: When you test this from your own FTP client machine, how are you connecting the FTP client machine to the Internet? Are you connecting it to the same LAN (and thus behind the same NAT) as the FTP server? Or are you connecting it to some outside network (like maybe using your smartphone in hotspot mode so your FTP client is effective connected to the Internet via your wireless carrier's network instead of your home Wi-Fi/broadband)?

Comment: So when you say ***"when i try to access from the browser it says that the connection is refused"*** what "Browser" are you referring to exactly just to be sure that's clear here as well.

Comment: @Spiff I tried in the same LAN and on other internet, like phone's network instead wifi, or in anther house with another PC. Anyway, ftptest.net works fine but i'm unnable to connect typing something like "ftp://192.140.xx.xxx" on phone's browser or on my app. Also on any PC outside my network.

Comment: @McDonald's i'm using Opera and Chrome, on URL I send "ftp://192.140.xx.xxx" and it's refused. But on my LAN IP works.

Comment: Ok, now I know that it's possible to access my server from anywhere because someone from India was uploading with anonymous login. I just banned his IP and removed anonymous login... Anyway, i'm still unable to make a connection, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, today i made the test again, outside my network and everything was working good... so, i don't know what was the problem but it's solved, thanks Spiff and McDonald's for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I just made the same tests again and today is working, I don't know why, maybe I was testing inside my network with an external IP Adress without knowing, just maybe.... But my problem is solved now.

Comment: You can comment instead of using answer

Comment: @yass This is an answer by the OP.

Comment: Hi @yass I made this Question and that was the "solution" haha. Anyway, I don't know what I can do, so I'll answer my own question.